# Uploading my ASP.NET website?

Tags: asp.net, linux, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

So, bit of silly question here but browsing google didn't really get me any good information.

I've just finished my first website using ASP.net, I've been building it with visual studio but now I need to upload it my web server.

So there I went, popped Filezilla and tried to upload my whole folder. No dice.

My question is, what needs to be uploaded? And is there any step I need to take in Visual Studio before uploading?

Comment: You said "no dice" that doesn't explain the problem. What, specifically, is happening?

Comment: when I try to access my website, i get a file listing and when i try to view one of them, i just get a html text version of my pages.

Comment: Just be sure. Does your web server supports ASP.NET??? Does it run on IIS or ASP.NET Mono?

Comment: i've now used the publish website fucntion like you instructed me, but i get the same results, my webserver is linux, is this a problem?...

Comment: You have to make sure your server support mod_mono in order for asp.net to run (http://www.mono-project.com/Mod_mono)

Comment: Hidden question for tutorial. Questions that ask for the explanation of a technology as a whole are out of scope.

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE:**

In order for asp.net to run in linux you need to make sure to install [mod_mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Mod_mono)

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

[Scott Gu will show you how to](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/29/vs-2010-web-deployment.aspx)

Since a picture is worth a thousand words here you have two!

To publish ***Web applications**

[image]

[image]

**EDIT**

To publish **Web sites**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't have the Publish option in my Visual Studio 2010, I do have "publish website", which does not allow me to upload it via FTP... why is that?

Comment: That is because it is not a web application but a web site. You should use the publish web site option then. You can use an ftp location to publish from there. Look at my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ASP.NET with Linux, you will need to use Mono.

More information about configuring your server can be found at the 
[Mono ASP.NET FAQ](http://www.mono-project.com/FAQ%3a_ASP.NET)

It appears that you do not have the mod_mono Apache module installed (or installed correctly) - so your files are being interpreted as text files.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Publish feature in Visual Studio. There should be a nice little wizard to follow and FTP is one of the options.

Comment: I don't have the Publish option in my Visual Studio 2010, I do have "publish website", which does not allow me to upload it via FTP... why is that?

Answer (score 0):

You need an IIS server to host ASP.Net sites and applications. I think the reason you're getting html-type pages back when you request ASPX pages is because the server isnt' IIS or ASP.Net compatible. The pages aren't being handled by the relevant IIS module so your server is serving the unprocessed ASPX pages back to you without 'filling-in' the dynamic server-generated bits.

All responders have given great advice about the use of `Publish ...` wizard in Visual studio.

FYI if you're pre-compiling your site you just need the `web.config`, `.aspx` and `.ASCX` markup pages (not the .cs or .designer.cs files) and the application DLLs (from the /obj/Release directory).

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

you should download the Microsoft Visual Studio Web Deployment Project. then after downloading install it at yoour pc. restart your Visual Studio. open the project and right click on the Project and click "Add web deployment Project". give project a path and build. You can find the deployable project at the path given of Web deployment project.